# How to inform binding that property value has changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding, textbox

I have a class with a int property called X. I binded it to Left property of a textBox. But when I change my class X value, textBox does not move. What to do to inform binding that my property value has changed so that textBox will move right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 3):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged.